# Android; Application has stopped. Simple Animation Error

Tags: java, android

My application splash screen is set to have one image fade in, then another, and then after the second one finishes, it's set to start my Main activity.

As soon as my second image is almost done fading in, it crashes.

Here is my SplashScreen activity;

```
package com.example.gymbuddy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);

    ImageView gym = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.gym);
    gym.startAnimation(fade1);

    ImageView buddy = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.buddy);
    buddy.startAnimation(fade2);
        fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Main.class);
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    ImageView gym = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    gym.clearAnimation();

    ImageView buddy = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    buddy.clearAnimation();

}

}
```

Comment: Please show us a logcat or the stacktrace of the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm willing to bet it's one of two things.

Either Main.class does not exist

OR

Main.class is not declared in your manifest as an Activity.

You should have something like this in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Main" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: It is though. I took out the whole chunk of code dealing with the onAnimationEnd and just left

    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Main.class);
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
                SplashScreen.this.finish();

Now it goes straight to my Main.Class (Predictable since it doesn't wait for the animation to end now) This was to make sure my intent and class fields were working correctly.

Comment: Did you also take out the onPause()? Maybe the problem is in there...a logcat or stacktrace would allow us to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I took out the onPause() and everything is working now! Thank you!
Can anyone explain why this is? What happens if the user clicks home during the animation now?

Comment: It probably has to do with the ImageViews, maybe there was a nullpointer there. I don't know anyone can tell you for sure what the error was without you giving us a stacktrace or a logcat.